# Query response value getting passed from my model to my controller?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, async-await

I am building a node js server with a mysql db. I am getting the proper response from my db, but my model is not properly sending the response to my controller, or my controller is not waiting for the async function to finish. response in my controller file comes back as undefined. Here is my code:

Model:

```
const sqlDb = require('../../db/index.ts');

module.exports = {
  getNProducts: (page = 0, n = 5) => {
      let offset = page * n;
      if (offset > 0) {
        sqlDb.query(`SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ${n}, ${offset}`, (err, res, feilds) => {
            if (err) {
                return;
            } else {
                return res;
            }
        });
        } else {
        sqlDb.query(`SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ${n}`, (err, res, feilds) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                return res;
            };
          });
        }
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
 const productModel = require('../models/productModel.ts');
    
    module.exports = {
        getProducts: async(req, res) => {
          let response = await productModel.getNProducts();
          res.send(response).status(200);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sqlDb.query()` calls inside your `getNProducts()` function use a callback method and is actually not returning a promise. You can try rewriting your `getNProducts()` function to return a promise like this.

```
module.exports = {
  getNProducts: (page = 0, n = 5) => {
    const offset = page * n;
    const limitString = (offset > 0)  ? `LIMIT ${n}, ${offset}` : `LIMIT ${n}`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sqlDb.query(`SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY id DESC ${limitString}`, (err, res, feilds) => {
          if (err) {
              reject(err);
          } else {
              resolve(res);
          }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the `productModel.ts` the `getNProducts` function is not an async function so it doesn't return a promise

I recommend This, it is the clearest way I have ever seen to explain what is  async await
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp

What is actually happening is in the controller the
`let response = await productModel.getNProducts();`

doesn't await a promise to resolve because `productModel.getNProducts()` doesn't return is an async function (doesn't return a promise)

you could edit the `getNProducts` to look like this

```
getNProducts: async (page = 0, n = 5) => { // now this return a promise
  let offset = page * n;
  if (offset > 0) {
   await sqlDb.query(`SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ${n}, ${offset}`, (err, res, feilds) => {// and now you await for it here
        if (err) {
            return;
        } else {
            return res;
        }
    });
    } else {
   await sqlDb.query(`SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ${n}`, (err, res, feilds) => { // and here too
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } else {
            return res;
        };
      });
    }
```

}